# Solving a word problem using a generating function

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Question:** We want to divide 60 A students,20 B students and 20 C students in two tutorial groups of equal size(50), so that in each group we have at least 20 and at most 35 A students, at least 5 B students, and at least 5 C students.

How many different compositions are there to form a tutorial group? (Using a generating function)

How many different ways are there to divide the students among the tutorial groups?

**My solution far:**
The coefficient is $x^{50}$

$f(x) = (x^{25}+...+x^{35})(x^{5}+...+x^{15})^{2}$
$= x^{25}(1+...+x^{10})*x^{5}*x^{5}(1+...+x^{10})^{2}$
$=x^{35}(1+...+x^{10})(1+...+x^{10})^{2}$

Comment: Suppose we choose (25, 10, 15). There are $60 C 25 * 20 C 10 * 20 C 15$ ways for this to happen. This number is much larger than your coefficient of $x^{50}$ in the product and the total number of ways to divide the students is much larger than it.

Comment: how will this change my equation?

Comment: Your summands should be of the form $\binom{n}{k}x^k$, instead of $x^k$, for appropriate $n$ and $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is practical to "symmetrize" the constraints first. The $A$-students have to be partitioned in two groups with cardinality $\in[20,35]$, which actually means two groups with cardinality $\in[25,35]$. Similarly the $B$-students have to be partitioned in two groups with cardinality $\in[5,15]$ and the same holds for the $C$-students. The group to be sent to Tutor $1$ can be chosen in 
$$ \sum_{\substack{a\in[25,35]\\ b,c\in[5,15] \\ a+b+c=50}}\binom{60}{a}\binom{20}{b}\binom{20}{c} $$
ways, reasonably assuming that two different students with the same scores are distinguishable$^{(*)}$.
 By Vandermonde's identity
$$ \sum_{b+c=k}\binom{20}{b}\binom{20}{c}=\binom{40}{k}$$
hence the previous sum can be written as
$$ \sum_{a=25}^{35}\binom{60}{a}\left[\binom{40}{50-a}-\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\sum_{\substack{b+c=50-a\\ b<5\vee c<5\vee b>16\vee c>16}}\!\!\!\!\binom{20}{b}\binom{20}{c}\right] $$
etcetera. For sure it is better to approach the question through exponential generating functions, rather then ordinary generating functions, due to $(*)$.

Comment: How would I be able to solve it using ordinary generating functions?

Comment: @SamuelOyediran: I do not think you are supposed to, ordinary generating functions are definitely not the right tool for dealing with distinguishable students.